# How to apply a function to each element of a data.frame?

Tags: r

I want to convert a numeric value into a factor, if the value is below -2 then "down" should be the factor, if it is above 2 then "up" and between "no_change":

So far I thought about creating a function:

```
classifier <- function(x){
    if (x >= 2){
      return(as.factor("up"))
    }else if (x <= -2){
      return(as.factor("down"))
    }else {
      return(as.factor("no_change"))
    }
}
```

I could make it iterate (with a for loop) over the input and return a list, so I could use it with apply.

I want to apply this function to **all cells** of the data.frame, how can I do it?

mock data (`runif(15, min=-5, max=5)`):

```
c(1.11004611710086, -1.86842617811635, 1.72159335808828, -2.68788822228089, 
2.72551498375833, 3.67290901951492, -4.00984475389123, -2.39582793787122, 
4.22395745059475, -0.360892189200968, 1.35027756914496, 2.89919016882777, 
-0.158692332915962, -0.950306688901037, 3.39141107397154)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `DF <- iris[-5]` as sample data, you can use `cut`, as I suggested in the comments.

Try:

```
DF[] <- lapply(DF, cut, c(-Inf, -2, 2, Inf), c("down", "no_change", "up"))

head(DF)
##   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
## 1           up          up    no_change   no_change
## 2           up          up    no_change   no_change
## 3           up          up    no_change   no_change
## 4           up          up    no_change   no_change
## 5           up          up    no_change   no_change
## 6           up          up    no_change   no_change

tail(DF)
##     Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
## 145           up          up           up          up
## 146           up          up           up          up
## 147           up          up           up   no_change
## 148           up          up           up   no_change
## 149           up          up           up          up
## 150           up          up           up   no_change
```

Or, with RHertel's "mock_data":

```
cut(mock_data, c(-Inf, -2, 2, Inf), c("down", "no_change", "up"))
##  [1] no_change no_change no_change down      up        up        down     
##  [8] down      up        no_change no_change up        no_change no_change
## [15] up       
## Levels: down no_change up
```

---

***Benchmarks***

As I suggested in the comments, RHertel's approach is likely to be the most efficient. That approach uses pretty straightforward subsetting (which is fast) and `factor` (which is also generally fast).

On data the size you describe, you will definitely notice the difference:

```
set.seed(1)
nrow = 20000
ncol = 1000
x <- as.data.frame(matrix(runif(nrow * ncol, min=-5, max=5), ncol = ncol))

factorize <- function(invec) {
  factorized <- rep("no_change", length(invec))
  factorized[invec > 2]  <- "up"
  factorized[invec < -2]  <- "down"
  factor(factorized, c("down", "no_change", "up"))
}

RHfun <- function(indf = x) {
  indf[] <- lapply(indf, factorize)
  indf
}

AMfun <- function(DF = x) {
  DF[] <- lapply(DF, cut, c(-Inf, -2, 2, Inf), c("down", "no_change", "up"))
  DF
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(AMfun(), RHfun(), times = 10)
# Unit: seconds
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval
#  AMfun() 7.501814 8.015532 8.852863 8.731638 9.660191 10.198983    10
#  RHfun() 1.437696 1.485791 1.723402 1.574507 1.637139  2.528574    10
```

Comment: I hope it is the fastest one of the solutions, but at the purpose of the function is for this cases. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Llopis, No. I haven't tested, but I'm certain that RHertel's answer would be faster. It's just basic subsetting, which would be very efficient.

Comment: I would love to see a benchmark of these, my data.frames can have 20532 rows and 1000 columns... and the faster the better :)

Comment: @Llopis, Done. Benchmarking is generally easy to do, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

I'm generally not fond of `ifelse()`, so I'd probably introduce a new vector and treat the problem differently.

```
factorized <- rep("no_change", length(mock_data))
factorized[mock_data > 2]  <- "up"
factorized[mock_data < -2]  <- "down"
factorized <- as.factor(factorized)
#> factorized
#[1] no_change no_change no_change down      up        up        down      down      up        no_change no_change up        no_change no_change up       
#Levels: down no_change up
```

The data in this example is taken from the OP:

```
mock_data <- c(1.11004611710086, -1.86842617811635, 1.72159335808828, -2.68788822228089, 
           2.72551498375833, 3.67290901951492, -4.00984475389123, -2.39582793787122, 
           4.22395745059475, -0.360892189200968, 1.35027756914496, 2.89919016882777, 
           -0.158692332915962, -0.950306688901037, 3.39141107397154)
```

Thanks to @docendo discimus for an improvement of this answer with a helpful comment.

Comment: You may be interested in the benchmarks at my answer.

Comment: That's interesting, indeed. Thanks a lot, @AnandaMahto

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply` with identifier for rows **and** columns.

```
apply(yourDF, c(1, 2), classifier)
```

This is made for applying a function to every cell of a `data.frame`. It probably won't work on vectors.

Comment: I didn't know it could be used for all the data.frame, thanks! that might come handy later on

Comment: @Llopis in fact `apply` works on an array, and return depends on what is produced by the fun applied. it calls `as.matrix` on data.frame input and thus will coerce different types columns to the same type.